# Is there a way to figure out whether PyTorch model is on cpu or on the device?

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

I would like to figure out, whether the `PyTorch` model is on `cpu` or `cuda` in order to
initialize some other variable as `Torch.Tensor` or `Torch.cuda.Tensor` depending on the model.

However, looking at the output of the `dir()` function I see only `.cpu()`, `.cuda()`, `to()` methods which put the model on device, GPU or other device, specified in to. For `PyTorch` tensor there is `is_cuda` attribute, but no analogue for the whole model.

Is there some way to deduce this for a model, or one needs to refer to a particular weight?

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no such function for `nn.Module`, I believe this is because parameters could be on multiple devices at the same time.

If you're working with a single device, a workaround is to check the first parameter:

```
next(model.parameters()).is_cuda
```

As described [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/584).